# Kubuntu taskbar menu popups unusable

Tags: kubuntu, menu, taskbar

Just installed Kubuntu 16.04 again and for some reason the taskbar pop-up menus are unusable. When i click any icon (wifi, bluetooth, hidden icons etc.) the popup menu flashes up and disappears back down again. It happens with the system tray items, digital clock and even with application menu/launcher.

Everything is updated/upgraded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try a different mouse, the mouse could be defect.

Comment: hey thanks for your suggestion, a good one actually, only it happens with touchpad and other mice too.  Think i'll just reinstall the damn thing, feck it

Comment: Never had that issue with Kubuntu 16.04, runs pretty stable, so i thought maybe aged mouse, but doesn't seem to be the case.When reinstall, don't forget `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` to come to `16.04.1`.Some issues still left,  `System Setting`-GUI crashes pretty often but works....

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it was because I set the `Focus stealing prevention` to `High`.

Since you can't bring up the options from the menu as normal (oops), using

`App Menu -> Settings -> Configure Desktop
  -> Window Management -> Window Behavior -> Select [Focus] tab`

From a command line, type

`kcmshell4 kwinoptions`

Choose the Focus tab (already selected for me), scroll down to `Focus stealing prevention` and choose something less aggressive. `Medium` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed all of the updates and upgrades of your system?
Try

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

and then

> sudo apt-get install aptitude

after install aptitude, upgrade your system

> sudo aptitude dist-upgrade

Something on kde must be missing, and these commands might help.

Comment: I guess re-installing also helps

Comment: I haven't tried to reinstall kde on kubuntu though, it seemed complicated at that time. These commands I've suggested usually fix most of my problems with kde.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your suggestions but the problem remains.  Think this could be another wild ubuntu goose chase that results in failure after 354354258 hours of searching, so i think i'll just reinstall the thing and be done with it.  

Once again, thanks for the suggestions!